# Do Pokestops give Lucky Egg, Incense or Lure Module?

Tags: pokemon-go

I believe I only got these from the level ups. I'm wondering if Pokestops give Lucky Egg, Incense or Lure Module?

Comment: Why did this question get so many downvotes? It's a legit question.

Comment: @freekvd, "does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Incense** can be received through leveling rewards and in-game purchases.

> The Incense is one of the Items both purchasable and found in Pokemon Go. From the start, you are given 2 as you begin the game. They can also be bought in the Store for 80 PokeCoins for 1, 500 for 8 Incense, and 1,250 for 25 Incense, the in game currency.

**Lucky eggs** are received from leveling rewards and in-game purchases.

> The Lucky Eggs are purchasable Items in Pokemon Go
>   Certain experience levels gained will also Reward you with Lucky Eggs, like achieving Level 9

**Lure Modules** are received from leveling rewards and through in-game purchases.

> The Lure Modules are purchasable Items in Pokemon Go
>   Additionally, when the trainer reaches certain levels - like level 8, they will also receive a free Lure Module.

[IGN wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Lure_Modules)

Comment: Do we have any ***actual proof*** that you can get Incense from Pokestops? IGN Wiki is probably the worst source, and it just links to Lure Modules.

Comment: Pokestops do have some sort of level system. Pokestops are landmarks give out a higher chance of better items.

Comment: You state that you can get them from leveling or by purchase, but don´t answer the question.  Your source doesn´t deny the posibility of getting these items from a stop (it doesn´t  say you can either but still)

Comment: [here](http://heavy.com/games/2016/08/pokemon-go-guide-tips-pokestop-item-drop-rates-possibility-possibilities-pokeballs-balls-potions-probability/) and [here](http://pokemongohub.net/pokemon-go-pokestop-drops-drop-rates/) are some drop tables. I have seen no proven cases where incense has been a drop from a pokestop.

Answer (score 1):

No. You only receive Lucky Eggs, Incense, and Lure Modules either through the store or as rewards for levelling up.

Comment: Ive received them from PokeStops..

Comment: @Timelord64 I work right next to two pokestops and spin them all day, and I've never received a single one. I haven't heard of anyone else receiving them either. They're the main thing to buy with microtransactions, so why would they drop from pokestops?

Comment: So are pokeballs.. I'm not sure why the developers do what they do, but you could still get unlucky. Ive also only just received the second incubator.. im not sure you even get the drops from leveling at that point.

Comment: @Pyritie, what level are you? The things you can pick up from stops get better as you increase in trainer level.

Comment: @Andrew, I have had at least incense drop at level 7

Comment: @Andrew level 14, almost 15. All of my incense/lucky eggs/lure modules have came from level up rewards.

Comment: @Timelord64 You get an Incubator at lvl 6, and Lure module at lvl 8. Are you sure you haven't gotten those items just from leveling?

Comment: @Lyrion, it seems you would have to be right on the Lure Module. I just checked, and I have actually jumped up to 8 with only 1 lure. That said, I have visibly watched the other levels, and have definetly retrieved incense from a stop

Comment: You get two lucky eggs at 20 (my friend told me), I am 18 and never got any at pokestops

Answer (score 0):

I'm level 18, I have never seen a lure module or incense from a pokestop, but I HAVE received one lucky egg from a pokestop. I was a level 10 or 11 at the time.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't a regular egg?

Answer (score -2):

I received a LUCKY EGG at a pokestop. Both my husband and son didn't believe me until they saw my lucky egg count at 2. My husband checked to see if I had made any purchases, and he didn't find any. My son still doesn't believe me and thinks I'm lying. But I'm not lying and I'm not stupid, I can read when it said "LUCKY EGG". 
However we were at a location where lots of people congregate every evening where there are 3 pokestops and 2 more across the street and all 3 poke stops have lures going all night. I'm just saying that lucky eggs are possible at pokestops, though they VERY VERY RARE!

Answer (score -3):

actually you can recieve incense and lures from pokestops....because i have....but very rarely has it happened